# Search button does not work. How do I make it search a specific text

Tags: html, css, button, search

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>Search</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="header-right">
        <a href="./advanced.html">Advanced Search</a>
        <a href="./images.html">Images</a>
      </div>
    </div>    
    <div class="mainBody">
      <img
        src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"
        alt="google img"
      />
        <div class="search">
        <div class="search-input">
          <span class="material-icons"> search </span>
            <form action="https://google.com/search">
            <input type="text" name="q" autofocus>
        <span class="material-icons"> mic </span>
        </form>
        </div>
        <div class="search-buttons">
          <button type="submit" name="q" onclick='location.href="https://google.com/search?q="'>Google Search</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my Code. I have made my Google Search button clickable but it sends me to a generic google page. How do I change it so it searches whatever I type into the text box?

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you are not specifying the query parameter properly. Remove the `onclick` attribute of the button. google replaces the spaces between words with + character, so we have to perform this operation and then assign the url.

```
<script>
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let query = e.target.querySelector('input[name="q"]').value;
    query = query.replace(' ', '+');
    window.location.href = "https://google.com/search?q=" + 'query'
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To submit the form to the url specified under form action attribute you need to add the submit button within the form tags.
Therefore the code (div of class="search") can be simply edited as follows:

```
    <div class="search">
        <div class="search-input">
            <span class="material-icons"> search </span>
            <form method="get" action="https://google.com/search">
                <input type="text" name="q" autofocus>
                <span class="material-icons"> mic </span>
                <button type="submit"> Google Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```